# Subtract all elements in an array from each other consecutively

Tags: matlab, vectorization

As the question says: 
`x = [1 2 3]`

`1 - 2 - 3 = -4`
How do I get my `-4`?
Without a for-loop.

`diff` doesn't work. I don't get how Matlab has a way to SUM, but not a way to subtract.

Comment: `x(1) - sum(x(2:end))` would do. Caution is required for the special case of an empty vector, though.

Comment: Also can be done by dot product with a vector such as [1 - 1... - 1]'

Comment: Thank you. The x array is my definition in a function so it won't ever be empty.

Comment: @matanj Can you explain that more? Dot product how?

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd operation, I doubt there's a builtin function for that, but an easy way to do it would be:

```
2*x(1)-sum(x)
```

Comment: This is quite clever. Factor out the negative one, and turn it into a summation. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is using dot product:

```
y = x*[1 ; -ones(numel(x)-1, 1)];
```

Here x is assumed a row vector.

Though probably not the best solution in your case, it can be nice say if you want other pattern for the summation, e.g. with weights - just replace the vector to the right by a vector of weights.